# PowerShell performance issue

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am new to powershell. I use the following powershell script to copy file from a network share, but the time cost is ridiculously long compared to a traditional windows batch file. What could be the cause?

```
$dlls=get-childitem -path "\\myShare\myBinFolder" -include *.dll -recurse
copy-item $dlls -destination c:\bins
```

Thanks

### Update - 1 - 1:38 PM 1/13/2011

Why Get-ChildItem is So Slow?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to optimize this is to avoid assigning it to a variable. Try this

```
Get-ChildItem *.dll -Path \\Myshare\Folder -recurse | % { Copy-item $_.FullName -destination C:\bins }
```

You can use Measure-Command to measure how much time these two methods are taking. You can do that by:

```
(Measure-Command {     Get-ChildItem *.dll -Path \\Myshare\Folder -recurse | % { Copy-item $_.FullName -destination C:\bins } }).Milliseconds
```

and

```
(Measure-Command {$dlls = Get-ChildItem *.dll -Path \\Myshare\Folder -recurse; copy-item $dlls -Destination C:\bins}).Milliseconds
```

Comment: I am new to PowerShell, could you explain your script a little? Especially the part behind the pipe symbol. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. % is the short form for Foreach-object. In this case, we are using pipe to send the objects as they are generated. In your initial code, all the objects are generated and assigned to a variable. In my example, each object as it gets generated, gets copied immediately.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a way to measure how much time it takes. Let me know if you see any difference.

Comment: Hmm, I would think that assigning to a variable would be a shade faster since the formatting engine doesn't run in that case.

Comment: I guess if the memory impact is great enough it could impact performance by storing the results rather then streaming them but only for a fairly large set of results.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use the `Include` parameter.  Use the `Filter` parameter instead.  Include will require every file to be returned from the share and filtered locally.  Using `Filter` should allow the filtering to happen on the remote end.

```
$dlls = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\myShare\myBinFolder" -Filter *.dll -recurse
```

or using positional feature of these parameters:

```
$dlls = Get-ChildItem \\myShare\myBinFolder *.dll -r
```

In fact, the only time I would ever use `Include` over `Filter` is if I needed to specify multiple filter terms (Include takes a string array) e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem . -inc *.h,*.cpp,*.rc -r
```

Answer (score 3):

All you really need from the remote system is a list of the full paths to the .dll files in that share.  Get-childitem is overkill for that, and has known issues working with large directory structures remotely.

See if this isn't a lot quicker:

```
cmd /c dir \\Myshare\Folder\*.dll /b /s |% {Copy-Item $_ -destination C:\bins}
```

Note: the double backslash in the UNC is showing up as a single in the post.
How do I fix that?

Comment: Indent four spaces to get code formatting (or use the toolbar button on the editor toolbar).

Comment: Note that using `cmd /c` will mangle some non-ASCII characters. PowerShell is unable to find some files again when I get their name via cmd.

Comment: Noted.  But in this application, finding non-ASCII characters in a .dll filename seems unlikely.